# Null reference exception with INotifyPropertyChanged when WPF DataGrid selection is not visible?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, nullreferenceexception

I have a `DataGrid` control in which the user can select multiple items. After selecting the items and pressing a button, I iterate over each and edit a property. When this property is changed, the `INotifyPropertyChanged` events fire. It all works beautifully. However I have noticed that **if I select two or more items** and scroll such that one of the items is well out of view and *then* press the button the program will crash and give me a null reference exception in the `NotifyPropertyChanged()` method telling me that the `PropertyChangedEventHandler` is null. The code works normally if I remove the `NotifyPropertyChanged()` call from the property's setter, so for now that's what I'm doing, but why would this happen? It works as expected regardless of scroll position if I only have one item selected.

In my model class, which implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, I have these:

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    // ...
    public bool IsScheduled
    {
        get { return isScheduled; }
        set { isScheduled = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(self.ToString()); }
    }
    // ...
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

Elsewhere in the ViewModel I make this simple call which triggers the error:

```
process.IsScheduled = true;
```

If I check the values of the selected values list when the error occurs, all of the selected items *are* detected. it seems something happens with the event when they are invisible.

Why does the visibility of the item in the view affect whether the event handler is null?

Comment: You have updated the original question to add "   if (PropertyChanged != null)"   Don't update questions based on answers.  It proves difficult for people coming later to understand what the problem was and how it has been fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code like so:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Always check for `null` because if there is no event handlers attached, it will throw `NullReferenceException`. **Besides that** you should always use temp variable when raising events because any object can add/remove handlers to it at any time.

**Edit:**

Depending on your .NET Framework version, you could also improve the `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "" )
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

And then notify simply using `NotifyPropertyChanged();` without explicitly passing property name to method since `[CallerMemberName]` gives you the the name of the caller automagically.

This (might) lead to less typing and less room for bugs in your code due to misspelled or changed property names.

Comment: Thank you, I always appreciate code corrections, but do you know why the handler would be null in the first place in this specific situation?

Comment: @mikkoviitala - and it is a guess :)

Comment: @ssb Despite you accepted the answer already, I made a little edit to it.

Comment: [CallerMemberName] is not recommended as it incurs a performance hit. Adding a reflection based lookup should always be done cautiously, doing so to just make the developers life easier is questionable. If you want to make it easier, add a code snippet.

Comment: As far as I know, compiler resolves caller names, no reflection is involved.

Answer (score 1):

Best practise with any event handler is to test for null before calling it...

```
if(PropertyChanged != null) this.PropertyChanged....
```

I'm also curious why you would let a string.empty default value be used?

Because the handler is created within WPF and not explicitly created in code, you have no control about whether a handler exists - add the check and you should be ok.

Comment: Do you have any idea why the handler is null in this specific situation?

Comment: My guess is that the WPF binding 'engine' is wisely removing binding for out of view items or disposing them controls when not visible, if you are using a virtualizing panel - that is the most likely reason. I've never implemented the handler without a check so it's never come up for me.

Comment: OK. I'll stop assuming that properties should always "exist" and I'll be more rigorous about checking for null references in the future. In my mind it seemed like the program would be fundamentally broken if that event handler didn't fire correctly, but I'm realizing that a lot of this is based around a flawed understanding of a few different things on my part.

Answer (score 0):

simpler even still:

```
PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
```

vs

```
if(PropertyChanged != null) 
PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
```

1 line vs 2